# how to set boxes in array with at least 1 neighbor equal to 1

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to go through an array and figure out which ones have at least 1 immediate neighbor..

the answer I'm getting is

```
display
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 1 

 display
11111
10001
11111
11111
11111

box :1 :1

box :1 :3
```

which is perfect. I am able to see from the output which ones have exactly 1 neighbor array[1][1] and array[1][3].

Now how do I set those 2 only (array[1][1] and array[1][3]) = 1?

Comment: what do you mean by "set those only ... = 0"? they are already 0.

Comment: my mistake. I meant 1.

Comment: now get another array, of two indexes, at the level of the main function stack, store the above points in it and then read the points in the array and make them 1 at the end.

Comment: @myohmy so you're talking about the morphological "dilate" filter with a 3x3 kernel?

Comment: I'm new to programming. Not sure what "the morphological "dilate" filter with a 3x3 kernel" means

Comment: You don't account for index overflows/underflows. If something is unclear, searching the web might help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use the nested 'display' loop multiple times, it'd be ideal to factorise that into its own function:

```
void Draw(int array[5][5]) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; ++y) 
            std::cout << array[x][y] << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Likewise, your 'finding neighbours' checks can be shortened drastically with an additional nested loop.

This will also make solving your problem much easier:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Draw(int array[5][5]) {
    cout << endl;
    for (unsigned x = 0; x < 5; ++x) {
        for (unsigned y = 0; y < 5; ++y)
            cout <<  array[x][y] << ' ';
        cout << '\n';
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    int num = 0;
    cout << "How many neighbours?: "; //Asks user for the number of neighbours they'd like to check for.
    cin >> num; //Saves the number of neighbours to look for in 'num'

    int array[5][5];
    int dummyarray[5][5]; //A spare array we'll use to keep track of which boxes have the specified number of neighbours.

    for (unsigned x = 0; x < 5; ++x) { 
        for (unsigned y = 0; y < 5; ++y)
            array[x][y] = 1; //Here we fill our original array with 1's
    }

    for (unsigned x = 0; x < 5; ++x) { 
        for (unsigned y = 0; y < 5; ++y)
            dummyarray[x][y] = 1; //Now we fill our dummy array with 1's so it's the same as our original array
    }

    Draw(array); //Here we call the Draw function, which prints our array for us.

    array[1][1] = 0;
    array[1][2] = 0; //Set some values of our original array to 0
    array[1][3] = 0;

    for (unsigned x = 0; x < 5; ++x) { //Here's where the checking starts
        for (unsigned y = 0; y < 5; ++y) {
            if (array[x][y] == 0) { //If we find a 0, start checking for neighbours of that 0 that are also 0's
                int count = -1; //Because this method counts the original box (array[x][y]) when searching for 0's, we anticipate this by removing one from the count, so that we get the correct number of neighbours
                for (int vertical = -1; vertical < 2; ++vertical) { //This loop checks boxes above and below our original box
                    for (int horizontal = -1; horizontal < 2; ++horizontal) { //This loop checks boxes side to side of our original box
                        if (vertical + y >= 0 && vertical + y < 5 && horizontal + x >= 0 && horizontal + x < 5) { //If we're inside the array bounds (ie, if we're not trying to access array[-1][-2] or something similar which would undefined behaviour), continue
                            if (array[x + horizontal][y + vertical] == 0) //If the box we're checking is a 0, add 1 to the number of neighbours our original box has
                                ++count;
                        }
                    }
                }
                cout << "(" << x << ", " << y << "): " << count << endl; 
                if (count == num) dummyarray[x][y] = 0; //If the box we just checked has the number of neighbours we're looking for, mark it in the dummy array.
            }
        }
    }
    for (unsigned x = 0; x < 5; ++x) {
        for (unsigned y = 0; y < 5; ++y)
            array[x][y] = dummyarray[x][y]; //Here we copy all of dummyarray's data to our original array.
    }
    Draw(array); //Finally, we draw our array again with Draw()

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I had something similar from your code but something is bugging me a bit.. if you set..    if (count == 2) array[x][y] = 1;   to    if (count == 1) array[x][y] = 1; , which will change cells that have only on neighbor to 1, you will see that the last of the 3 zero is still = 0. But in reality, the middle zero is supposed to stay 0 and the rest 1.

Comment: It should work just fine now. Make sure to keep `if (count == 2) dummyarray[x][y] = 0;` unchanged.

Comment: thanks. the count==2 is correct when we want to find if they have 2 neighbors.. What if we want to find if they only have 1 neighbor? so that if they have only one neighbor, they turn into 1;

Comment: Ok. thank! I guess that works as well. I was thinking of building it a different way but I'll take this. Thank you!

Comment: actually I think I'm still confused. I don't really understand the "shortening" you did. Are you able to do the same thing but with the way I coded it instead. I'm just trying to understand what's going on.

Comment: Yep, you totally can. I removed the code for displaying the array and put it in its own function. This is often useful in C++, and there's more info on it at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/. The shortening of the checking code was because there was a predictable pattern in the way you checked neighbouring boxes. I'll edit it a bit and add a solution with your style of coding as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really confused why you're trying to match the full neighborhood if all you need is "at least one neighbor is 1". Is there a reason you can't just do:

```
// going through the loop to figure out which ones have at least 1 neighbor
  for (int x = 0; x <5 ; x++)
  {
      for (int y = 0; y <5 ; y++)
      {
           if (  (array[x][y] == 0 )
            && 
            (array [x-1][y] == 1 || array [x+1][y] == 1 || 
             array [x][y-1] == 1 || array [x][y+1] ==1 || 
             array [x+1][y+1]==1 || array [x-1][y-1]==1 || 
             array [x-1][y+1]==1 || array [x+1][y-1] == 1)
            )
            {
                cout << endl;
                cout << "box :" << x << " :" << y << endl;
            } 
      }
```

Oh and you should probably handle the cases at the borders.

```
int clamp04(int coord){return coord<0?0:(coord>4)?4:coord;}
```

and then use it like

```
// going through the loop to figure out which ones have at least 1 neighbor
  for (int x = 0; x <5 ; x++)
  {
      for (int y = 0; y <5 ; y++)
      {
           if (  (array[x][y] == 0 )
            && 
            (array [clamp04(x-1)][y] == 1 || array [clamp04(x+1)][y] == 1 || 
             array [x][clamp04(y-1)] == 1 || array [x][clamp04(y+1)] ==1 || 
             array [clamp04(x+1)][clamp04(y+1)]==1 || array [clamp04(x-1)][clamp04(y-1)]==1 || 
             array [clamp04(x-1)][clamp04(y+1)]==1 || array [clamp04(x+1)][clamp04(y-1)] == 1)
            )
            {
                cout << endl;
                cout << "box :" << x << " :" << y << endl;
            } 
      }
```

Also, as a side-note, if you're then setting those values to 1 the operation you're executing is a morphological filter operation known as ["dilation"](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/ImageProcessing-html/topic4.htm)

Comment: thanks peter. Well my main concern is to set those with 2 neighbors =1; I'm not really sure what dilations are